# ComponentOne reports : using IEnumerable as datasource

Tags: ienumerable, datasource, report, componentone

I have business objects that implement IEnumerable and I and need to use them as datasource of a ComponentOne report. But, the "myreport.DataSource.Recordset" is only accepting a DataTable.

Could I have some help to find how can a C1Report datasource be fed with IEnumerable BOs ?